# How to make Fluxbox stop making annoying sound effects?

Tags: sound, fluxbox

Whenever I open a new tab in Chrome, or pretty much interact with the UI in any way, Fluxbox makes some very annoying sound effects. Where can I disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was annoying me also! I solved it by doing the following on my system:

1. Opened 'gnome-control-center' via the terminal.
2. Selected the 'Sound Effects' tab.
3. Clicked the slider to 'Off' to the right of the 'Alert volume' slider.